# Is the center of the supergiant star a white dwarf?

Tags: white-dwarfs

[image]

According to An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics, there is a sentence in the book that describes a white dwarf at the center of a supergiant star.

As far as I know, in the case of a heavy star, the core of the heavy star is just an iron core, and if it collapses beyond the degenerative pressure, the core becomes a neutron star.

So, Is it correct to describe the center of a supergiant as a white dwarf?

Comment: Which book is this? Anyway , the text wdoes not claim that this model is correct. It is a toy model to make you appreciate the difficulty of the subject.

Comment: “iron white dwarf at  the center of a massive supergiant star”  is this sentence correct?  A white dwarf is a central region that remains after the giant stage. Is it right to refer to the star core still at the giant stage as a white dwarf?